# How to get access to data from outside the firestore onSnapshot method in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to react native and I encountered some problems when using firestore. I have retrieved data from firestore onSnapshot method and I want to get access to the data from outside the method. I tried using the state hook, setting the state of the variable to be `documentSnapshot.data()`, but the state only survives inside the onSnapshot method where outside it is undefined. Below is the code snippet:

```
const [document, setDocument] = useState();
const bookRef = firestore().collection('BookStore').doc(Type).collection('Books').doc(id); 

        bookRef.onSnapshot(documentSnapshot=>{
            setDocument(documentSnapshot.data());
            console.log(document['Author']); //<-Successfully log the data
        });
        console.log(document['Author']); //<- document becomes undefined
```

Can anyone show me how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: onSnapshot is asynchronous function, I think you need to use async/await or use promise based approach.

Comment: But the state variables are set after I refreshes the app. How can it be set immediately after the screen is loaded?

Comment: Not sure I get it. To set it immediately you can wrap your code in useEffect.

Comment: Already wrap in useEffect still got the same result

Comment: Could you share more of your code then? The whole functions where this code is wrapped should be enough?